# Symfony 3 find closest date from now

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have three database tables. user, meeting, group. The meetings and group table are manytomany associations from the user table. 
So I can do `user->getmeetings()`, or `user->getgroups()`.

I want to get just the next meeting comping up for the user, and I don't know how to achieve this. Whether by SQL Query or simply in the controller. Here is what I have done so far.

```
$loggedInUser = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\User')
        ->find($id);

    foreach ($loggedInUser->getMeetings() as $userMeetings) {
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['id'] = $userMeetings->getId();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['group'] = $userMeetings->getGroup();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['name'] = $userMeetings->getName();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['info'] = $userMeetings->getInfo();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['bring'] = $userMeetings->getBring();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['summary'] = $userMeetings->getSummary();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['files'] = $userMeetings->getFiles();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['meetingDate'] = $userMeetings->getMeetingDate();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['meetingAddress'] = $userMeetings->getMeetingAddress();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['time_diff'] = date_diff($userMeetings->getMeetingDate(), new \DateTime());
    }
```

I have added a `time_diff` field in the new array to calculate the time from now to the meeting time. All I need to do now is select the smallest one.
How can I do this? Thank you.

UPDATE - Below is my User Repository

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Meeting;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getComingMeeting()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->gte("meetingDate", new \DateTime('now')))
            ->orderBy(array("meetingDate" => Criteria::ASC))
            ->setMaxResults(1);
    $this->getMeetings()->matching($criteria);
}
}
```

Below is my User Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $first_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $last_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $email_address;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $phone_number;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $last_login;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $reset_password;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Meeting", inversedBy="users")
 */
private $meetings;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
 */
private $groups;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->groups = new arrayCollection();
    $this->meetings = new arrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->first_name;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $first_name
 */
public function setFirstName($first_name)
{
    $this->first_name = $first_name;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->last_name;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $last_name
 */
public function setLastName($last_name)
{
    $this->last_name = $last_name;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmailAddress()
{
    return $this->email_address;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $email_address
 */
public function setEmailAddress($email_address)
{
    $this->email_address = $email_address;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPhoneNumber()
{
    return $this->phone_number;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $phone_number
 */
public function setPhoneNumber($phone_number)
{
    $this->phone_number = $phone_number;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLastLogin()
{
    return $this->last_login;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $last_login
 */
public function setLastLogin($last_login)
{
    $this->last_login = $last_login;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getResetPassword()
{
    return $this->reset_password;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $reset_password
 */
public function setResetPassword($reset_password)
{
    $this->reset_password = $reset_password;
}

/**
 * @return arrayCollection|Meeting[]
 */
public function getMeetings()
{
    return $this->meetings;
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection|Group[]
 */
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}



}
```

below is my HomeControlller.php

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/home", name="home_show")
 */
public function showAction()

{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //logged in user
    $id = 1;

    $loggedInUser = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\User')
        ->find($id);

    foreach ($loggedInUser->getMeetings() as $userMeetings) {
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['id'] = $userMeetings->getId();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['group'] = $userMeetings->getGroup();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['name'] = $userMeetings->getName();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['info'] = $userMeetings->getInfo();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['bring'] = $userMeetings->getBring();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['summary'] = $userMeetings->getSummary();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['files'] = $userMeetings->getFiles();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['meetingDate'] = $userMeetings->getMeetingDate();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['meetingAddress'] = $userMeetings->getMeetingAddress();
        $nextMeeting[$userMeetings->getId()]['time_diff'] = date_diff($userMeetings->getMeetingDate(), new \DateTime());
    }


    $groups = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Group')
        ->findAll();

    return $this->render('home/show.html.twig', [
        'loggedInUser' => $loggedInUser,
        'groups' => $groups,
    ]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method in your `UserEntity` with a matching criteria on meeting collection

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

....

public function getComingMeeting()
{
   $criteria = Criteria::create()
     ->where(Criteria::expr()->gte("meetingDate", new \DateTime('now')))
     ->orderBy(array("meetingDate" => Criteria::ASC))
     ->setMaxResults(1);

  return $this->getMeetings()->matching($criteria);
}
```

see http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Comment: I have placed the public function inside my UserRepository class. It is unable to find $this->getMeetings(). However I have linked the repository class to the user entity. Also how does the expression know to look inside the meetings entity table, should it not be gte("meeting.meetingDate")? Have updated my question to include my user repository

Comment: You can't access to `$this->getMeetings()` from the entityRepo, you can only from entity. add this method directly in your entity. You don't need `meeting.MeetingDate` since your iterate on array collection of `Meeting`.

Comment: my initial $loggedInUser Object and foreach loop are inside my controller HomeController.php, inside a public function showAction(). Should I put that also inside my entity class User.php along with your code snippet?

Comment: When I add your public function getComingMeeting() in the Meeting Entity, I get an error Attempted to call an undefined method named "getMeetings" of class "AppBundle\Entity\Meeting". I tihink this is happening because the method getMeetings is inside the User Entity, not the Meeting entity. Do you know How I can relate the getMeetings()method coming from my user entity into the getComingMeeting which I placed inside the Meeting Entity\

Comment: Do I place your function getCOmingMeeting() inside the Meeting entity or the User Entity. When I put it in the user entity I get an error because it cannot find the method getComingMeeting() inside the Meeting Entity. However when I place it inside the Meeting Entity I get an error saying it cannot find the method $this->getMeetings() inside the Meeting Entity

Comment: Put `getComingMeeting` method in `UserEntity` then call it from crontroller
`$loggedInUser->getComingMeeting()`